# No warning when demoting double to float

Tags: c++, macos, g++, double

When I compile the following code on a Mac 64-bit machine with OSX 10.8 and g++ 4.2.1 no warning is generated.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    double d= 3.14159;
    float res= d;
    printf("%f\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, automatically demoting a double to a float is potentially very dangerous, but the compiler does not generate any warning. The only solution I could find was to use the flag *-Wshorten-64-to-32*.

It seems to me such an obvious mistake that I am surprised the compiler does not catch this error by default. Is there any reason why g++ does not catch this error by default? Is there a better way to generate the warning without using the *-Wshorten-64-to-32*?

In case you wonder, *-Wall* will not generate a warning either...

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The real appears to be "Why doesn't GNU/g++ apply -Wshorten-64-to-32 by default or as part of -Wall?" I don't believe there is a good answer for this. Simply enable such in your projects and move on. (There are many things in C/C++ which I would *require* warnings for or outright disallow, but then I'd be writing a compiler [for a derivative language] rejecting lots of code with the default settings..)

Comment: You specifically request demotion by writing **float** res = d;  I would consider it annoying if a compiler warned about this.

Comment: A lot of this boils down to the long-term experience of the development community... if many experienced programmers were getting bitten by unintended conversions like this, first GCC might enable the warning as part of `-Wall`, then someone would probably suggest a change to the Standard etc..  The fact that it's not warned about suggests very few people see there being much substance to your "potentially very dangerous".  Many similarly dangerous conversions are allowed by the Standard, and on balance they prove more convenient that troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Indeed I do not agree that this behavior is not dangerous, but I see your point. Say for example that my code is using double precision and it is important I keep such precision, but one of the function I call (or one other function called by this function) slice my double to a float (perhaps a function that takes by value a float parameter and not a double parameter). In this case it would be very nice to know that my double was sliced. I can always check for casts using grep, but silent demotion could be tricky to detect. Anyway, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is according to the standard:

> **4.8 Floating point conversions [conv.double]**
>
> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point type. If the
>   source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact
>   representation. If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion
>   is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Moreover, values floating point type can be converted to values of integer type:

> **4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]**
>
> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
>   that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.

Comment: While true, this doesn't discuss why g++ is not more warningful-by-default. (Of course, I don't think there is a good answer to *that* question..)

Comment: @user2864740 Agreed, the answer does not address warning policy of G++. But it is not completely irrelevant either. Not sure, maybe I should delete it :).

Comment: No, I think it's fine (and I also up-voted it) - it is good to have such information about. Just pointing out that I believe the OP is looking for more of a g++/implementation-specific rationale.